# Phonegap Writing to SQLite table

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

Really sorry to have to resort to asking questions on a forum but I have been banging my head all day trying to solve this problem.

I have a phonegap app which creates an SQLite database, creates a table, gets a JSON feed from tinternet and then feeds that data into the table.

Everything seems to be ok up until the bit where the database is supposed to be populated. The  "insertProperty" function just doesn't run. Any help would be really awesome!

Here are the relevant code snippets.

```
x$(document).on('deviceready', function () {

    // CREATE DATABASE
var localDatabase = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("localDB", "1.0", "Local DB", 5000000);
console.log("Database Loaded");
// CREATE properties TABLE
var query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS properties (propertyid INT, propertytype text, address text,  postcode text, clientid INT);"
db.transaction(function (trxn) {
    trxn.executeSql(query,  [],  callback,
    function (transaction, error) { //error callback
        console.log(error);
    });
});
}



function insertProperty(db, data) {
var query = "INSERT INTO properties (propertyid, propertytype, address, postcode, clientid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);"
db.transaction(function (trxn) {
    trxn.executeSql(query,[data.propertyid, data.propertytype, data.address, data.postcode, data.clientid],
    function (transaction, resultSet) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    function (transaction, error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    );
});
}




x$().xhr("http://myurl.com", { // GET JSON FEED

    async: true,callback: function () { try {
        var dataArray = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // PARSE JSON FEED
        console.log("Loading live data");
        dataArray.forEach(function (thedata) { // LOOP DATA
            console.log(thedata.address);
            insertProperty(localDatabase, thedata);
        });
         console.log("Rendering Live Data");
        renderDataset(dataArray)
    } catch (e) { // failed to retrieve data
            console.log("There was a problem, Loading local data");
            getStoredProperties(localDatabase, function (offlineData) {
                renderDataset(offlineData);
            });
         }
    }
});
```

The script runs as far as "console.log(thedata.address);" and shows me an address but then as soon as it tries to run the insertProperty function, it bails out and goes straight to the "console.log("There was a problem, Loading local data");" bit.

Thanks again for any help you can provide.
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you're defining local variable `localDatabase` in scope of "deviceready" function and therefore it's not accessible when you're looping data inside xhr callback function.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks Zvona, I feel like a dumbass now! Still, at least it's working now I declared window.localDatabase instead of var = localDatabase...

Comment: Just one more question Zvona - the script now runs ok but I am getting an error when calling the insertProperty function. 

    {"message":"SQL statement error : no such table: properties"}

I guess the table isn't being created but I don't know why... I changed the transaction to localDatabase.transation(function (txrn) { but that didn't help...

Comment: You need to execute every function (even x$().xhr) inside deviceready callback. Now you're executing XHR directly and the callback may be fired before deviceready occurs.